# How do I convert the numbers in my Vector<Object> into int?

Tags: java, object, vector, casting, integer

How do I convert the numbers in my vector into int? I'm trying the numbers in my object array into int values for my if statenebt, but I can't find a way to do so. Can anyone help tell me what I would need to do?

```
private static void test() {
    Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
    vector.add(1);
        vector.add(2);
        vector.add(5);
        vector.add(6);
        System.out.println("\nThe Vector is: " + vector);
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
        {      
          int d = vector.get(i);
          if(d%2 == 0) 
          {
              System.out.println(d);
             
          }
}
```

I tried using cast, i.e., `(int)`, but it didn't work. The result I want is to print out only the odd numbers in the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you are trying to cast `Object` elements directly to `int`, which will result in a compilation error. To achieve your goal of printing only the odd numbers in the vector, you need to perform the following steps:

1. Iterate through the `Vector<Object>`.
2. Check if each element is an instance of `Integer`.
3. If it's an `Integer`, cast it to `int` and then check if it's odd.

Here's a modified version of your code that accomplishes this:

```java
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        vector.add(1);
        vector.add(2);
        vector.add(5);
        vector.add(6);
        
        System.out.println("\nThe Vector is: " + vector);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
            Object obj = vector.get(i);
            if (obj instanceof Integer) {
                int d = (int) obj;
                if (d % 2 != 0) {
                    System.out.println(d);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, we use the `instanceof` operator to check if an element is an instance of `Integer`. If it is, we cast it to `int` and then check if it's an odd number before printing it. This way, you will only print the odd numbers from your vector.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Cast `Object` object to `Integer` object. Then let auto-boxing implicitly change `Integer` object to `int` primitive.

```
int d = ( Integer ) vector.get(i);  // Cast `Object` to `Integer`, then implicit auto-boxing to `int`.
```

Even better, revise your code:

```java
SequencedCollection < Integer > inputs = List.of ( 1 , 2 , 5 , 6 );
for ( Integer input : inputs )
{
    if ( input % 2 != 0 )
    {
        System.out.println ( input );  // Print odd numbers.
    }
}
```

### Auto-boxing

You said:

> I tried using cast e.i. (int)

Collections such as `Vector` hold objects, not primitives. When you add a primitive literal such as `1` or `5` to such a collection, Java automatically converts these `int` values into objects of the wrapper class `Integer`. This conversion is known as [auto-boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_(computer_science)#Autoboxing).

In other words, your code:

```
vector.add(2);
```

… is equivalent to a call to [`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)), returning a `Integer` object:

```
vector.add( Integer.valueOf( 1 ) );  // Making an `Integer` object from a primitive `int`.
```

Your call `vector.get(i)` returns an object, not a primitive. So your cast `(int)` makes no sense. Casting does not work across the chasm between primitives and objects. Crossing that chasm is the work of boxing.

### Cast

As discussed above, you actually put `Integer` objects into your `Vector`. But you declared the `Vector` as holding objects of the superclass [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html). When retrieving, you get `Object` objects rather than `Integer` objects.

You must cast from `Object` to the concrete class `Integer`.

```
Integer d = (Integer) vector.get(i) ;
```

As discussed above, this cast `(Integer)` is *not* the same as your cast attempt `(int)`.

### Declare specific type

But this is a fix to your less than optimal code. If your collection holds `Integer` objects, say so.

You need not repeat the `Integer` type on the right side of the assignment; the compiler can infer that fact from the left side.

```
Vector < Integer > vector = new Vector <> ( );
```

After specifying the more concrete type, we no longer need that cast.

```
Integer d = inputs.get ( i );  // Retrieving an `Integer` object from a known list of `Integer` objects. So no cast needed.
```

### Avoid `Vector` class

Another problem: [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Vector.html) is an old class from the earliest versions of Java, before the [Java Collections Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) was built. That class is now legacy, as noted in its Javadoc.

### `SequencedCollection` & `ArrayList`

Instead, use a [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) implementation such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html).

By the way, use more descriptive names for your variables. Good names makes your code easier to read and more [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code). So something like `inputs` rather than `vector`.

```
SequencedCollection < Integer > inputs = new ArrayList<>() ;
```

### `List.of`

Rather than call `add` multiple times, use the [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E,E)) feature for more compact code.

```
SequencedCollection < Integer > inputs = List.of ( 1 , 2 , 5 , 6 );
```

The `List` object returned by `List.of` is [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable), not allowing additions or deletions. That works in your situation.

### Enhanced `for` loop

To simply loop through a collection, you can use the enhanced `for` loop.

```
for ( Integer input : inputs )
```

So now our code looks like this:

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.SequencedCollection;

public class Nums
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        SequencedCollection < Integer > inputs = List.of ( 1 , 2 , 5 , 6 );
        System.out.println ( "Inputs: " + inputs );
        for ( Integer input : inputs )
        {
            if ( input % 2 == 0 )
            {
                System.out.println ( input );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

> Inputs: [1, 2, 5, 6]
>
> 2
>
> 6

### `!` means *not*

You said:

> I want is to print out only the odd number

Flip the logic of your `if` test by applying `!`.

```
if ( ! ( input % 2 == 0 ) ) { … odd number … }
```

Or, more simply, use `!=` for "not equals":

```
if ( input % 2 != 0 )
```

---

You seem to be working from a *very* old tutorial. I strongly recommend using more recent learning materials.

You might start with the free-of-cost [*Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) by Oracle.com. These are from the Java 8 era, so a bit out-of-date but still valid overall.

Also, I highly recommend [*Head First Java, 3rd Edition*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-java/9781492091646/) by Kathy Sierra, Bert Bates, Trisha Gee.

---

### Streams

Eventually you may learn to use streams.

Like this:

```java
List
        .of ( 1 , 2 , 5 , 6 )
        .stream ( )
        .filter ( input -> input % 2 == 0 )
        .forEach ( System.out :: println );
```

Or, this:

```java
SequencedCollection < Integer > inputs =
        Stream
                .of ( 1 , 2 , 5 , 6 )
                .filter (
                        ( Integer integer ) -> integer % 2 == 0
                )
                .toList ( );
```